# Mass ratio of solar-electric versus radioisotope thermo-electric power for propulsion; beyond how many AU do RTGs win?

Tags: design, solar-power, ion-thruster, rtg, electric-propulsion

Solar-electric propulsion has been used several times now in deep space missions. This question explores the scalability in comparison to [Radioisotope thermoelectric generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator) or other nuclear-based sources.

### Primary part

Suppose a deep-space mission where smallsats needs to be placed at several distances from the Sun in circular orbits. Each requires 1 kW of electrical power (thermal management for the coldest orbits is done with separate [radioisotope heating units](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23110/12102)).

Does solar-electric always win over RTGs in terms of mass? Below 1 AU it's almost certain that solar-electric power wins, but at what distance from the Sun would the cross-over point be where, *roughly speaking* the two types of power systems would be similar masses?

Reasonable extrapolation and estimation are fine, we don't need a design review. I'm just wondering if these points are in the asteroid belt or the Oort cloud.

### Secondary (optional) part

If the power requirement were much lower, say 1 W or 10 W, would the crossover point be roughly the same? Or does the scaling of mass with output power behave very differently for one versus the other?

---

Just fyi Juno had to [hibernate for 2.5 years](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15374/12102) because there wasn't enough sunlight near aphelion, and the *really*-deep-space probes all used RTGs.

Comment: Don't forget actual nuclear reactors, as well.

Comment: @ikrase I didn't, they're covered under "...or other nuclear-based sources." in the first sentence.

Comment: @RussellBorogove that's part of the question, yes. The mass of a power generation system may not drop linearly as the output rating drops (e.g. a 1 W RTG may not be 0.001 of the mass of a 1 kW RTG), and one might drop more slowly than the other.. It doesn't have to be exactly 1 W it could be 10 W if there's more data available. This might be a more difficult part of the question to answer.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I've changed to "two *types of* power systems". An ideal answer would identify the crossover point for a 1 W rating and a 1 kW rating. If one assumes that for both system types the mass scales the same way with power rating (as [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/40121/12102) does), then the two power ratings would have a crossover at the same distance from the Sun.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I appreciate the coaching! I've carefully refactored the question taking into account that an answer has already been posted. How does it look?

Comment: Yes, that’s much clearer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**With current technology: 4.3AU**.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator#Space), it appears that the most powerful flight-proven RTG had a power density of 5.4W/kg.  From [NASA](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/system/downloadable_items/715_Solar_Power_Tech_Report_FINAL.PDF), current (as of 2017) solar technology has a power density of 100W/kg.

The power output of a solar cell drops off with the square of the distance from the sun.  So, let's assume we have 1 kW at 1 AU.  The mass of this cell would be:

$$m_o = \frac{1000W}{100W/kg} = 10 kg$$

The mass as we move away from the sun is $m_{req} = m_oD^2$, where $D$ is the distance from the sun in AU.

The RTG's output is constant and you'd need a mass of 185 kg to get 1 kW.

Plotting this and finding the intersection gives you 4.3 AU.

---

From the NASA report:

> Solar Arrays: The types of solar arrays currently in use are: a) body-mounted arrays, b) deployable rigid arrays, and c) flexible fold out arrays. During the past 25 years, the specific power of solar arrays has improved from 30 W/kg to 100 W/kg. In the past decade, these advances have enabled several orbital and surface missions at Mars, as well as flyby and orbital missions to small bodies and inner planets.
>
> Limitations: In spite of these advances, SOP solar power systems are not attractive for the following future planetary mission concepts:
>
> 1. Outer planetary missions beyond Saturn, because of limited performance capabilities at low solar irradiance and low-temperature environments;
> 2. Low-altitude Venus aerial and surface missions, due to their limited operational capabilities at high temperatures, high/low solar irradiance, and corrosive environments;
> 3. Long-duration Mars surface solar powered missions, because of dust accumulation on solar arrays;
> 4. High-power, solar electric propulsion missions to small bodies and outer planets, because such solar arrays would be heavy, bulky, and could not function in LILT environments.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy and conclusive answer! I added a bit of info from the source in case the NASA link breaks, which happens from time to time as they move things around.

Comment: Both solar arrays and RTGs degrade significantly over time; it would be interesting to see how the break-even distance changes over time.

Comment: fyi I've just asked [Are few kilogram RTG's possible with similar mass-specific power to current designs?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41430/12102)