# What was the avg temperature of Voyager 1 before it warmed up it’s cameras for the ‘Family portrait’ photo in 1990

Tags: voyager, temperature

In 1990, it took Voyager 1 three hours to warm up its cameras for the [Family Portrait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Portrait_(Voyager)) photo looking back at our solar system.

What was the temperature of the camera before the warm up, or at least the average spacecraft temperature at that time?

Comment: Voyager had several very different temperatures since it had an RTG and a few strategically placed isotopic heaters as well, so "average spacecraft temperature" might not be so meaningful. Different but related: [How would the Voyagers finally die if allowed to transmit to the bitter end?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36001/12102) and [How cold are the Voyagers now? Colder than LOX? Colder than SOX?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23108/12102)

Comment: and [Did any of Voyagers' receivers' front ends take advantage of the "cold of space" to lower noise? (communications or radio/plasma science receivers)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31230/12102)